# Dynamic method definition in a class

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a PrestaShop module which fires off a POST request using a hook.

The hook gets called like so:

```
if(is_callable(array($moduleInstance, 'hook'.$hook_name)) {
    $moduleInstance->{'hook'.$hook_name}($hook_args);
}
```

Meaning to catch the hook event I need to have the method readily available in the class. So say I wanted to call a hook called `myCustomEvent`, I'd need the following:

```
class myModule extends Module {

    public function hookmyCustomEvent($params) {

    }

}
```

However, what I'm wanting to do is store a list of hook events in a database and fire them when the hook is called. But to do that I need a method defined in the class. What I'd like to be able to do is have a sort of "magic"/wildcard method that would catch them all starting with `hook`.

Is this possible?

Edit:

The methods don't exist, since I essentially want them to be dynamically called, executing another method.

Real code for examples:

```
public function hookactionValidateOrder($params) {
    $this->fireWebhook('actionValidateOrder', $params);
}

public function hookactionOrderStatusUpdate($params) {
    $this->fireWebhook('actionOrderStatusUpdate', $params);
}

public function hookactionUpdateQuantity($params) {
    $this->fireWebhook('actionUpdateQuantity', $params);
}

private function fireWebhook($event, $data) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, Configuration::get('HOOK_URL'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
        'event' => $event,
        'data' => $data
    ]));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: check this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call and see `__call()` method.

Comment: if all of the `hook<restOfTheName>` methods exist, you can use `method_exists($instance, 'hook'.$hookName)`, or `is_callable`. You _could_ use `__call` to catch calls to a non-existant method, too, but that's not a pretty solution

Comment: The methods don't exist, I essentially want to call a single method to fire a POST request whenever one of these methods are called, creating a webhook.

Comment: @BenFortune: Why don't you create a single `doHook` method, passing the hook name to it as an argument, have a `switch` in that `doHook` method and handle each hook name accordingly? Why bother implementing a _slow_ and error-prone `__call` method?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I have no control over the method names, they are pre-defined hooks hard-coded into PrestaShop. I activate the hook using `$this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder')` and create a method in my module with `public function hookactionValidateOrder(){}`. `doHook` would never be called.

Comment: @BenFortune: [This](https://eval.in/210971) might allow you to register methods prior to them being called. By making the methods private, any outside call will have to pass through to the `__call` method (of death), if the method name is valid, you can register it, and do whatever you need, then call it passing the arguments, and have the private method call the `fireWebhook` method safely

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The thing is, I want to retrieve the hooks from a database, so I don't want to hard-code each method in the class.

Comment: @BenFortune: In that case, you'll have to use an array of valid hook names, and if the name matches `hook<SomeValidName>`, call the `fireWebhook` method, if not, throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __call($methodName, array $params) {
    if (substr($methodName, 0, 4) === 'hook') {
        // this matches something starting with "hook" so pull your instructions from the db here
    }
}
```

Something like that would match a method without the need to explicitly define it as a class method, which I *think* was your intent?

Comment: Something like this is what I want, I've just heard bad things about relying on magic methods and wanted to know if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: Magic methods aren't a great solution and you're going to get a lot of reflexive "magic methods are bad" replies I'm guessing, but given the constraints you described in your question, I don't know of another way to solve it. You can't re-engineer the underlying technology, so you have to adapt to it. If you were building the entire system from scratch, you would definitely want to find a better way to implement this than to use magic methods.

Comment: @BenFortune: It does sound like you're dealing with a webservice... isn't there a wsdl you could parse?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It's not a webservice, it's an event-like feature hard-coded into PrestaShop. Say someone places an order, it will fire an event/hook that you can 'catch' and create an action for it. In my case creating a POST request that I can use to synchronise with my back-end services.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a method call on a dynamic definition use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func( array($moduleInstance, 'hook'.$hook_name) , $hook_args );
```

As for your request to execute all methods starting with `hook` i'd suggest the following:

```
class MyModule
{
    /* ... */
    public function executeHooks()
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);

        foreach ($methods as $method) {
            if (substr($method, 0, 4) == 'hook') {
                // Method is a hook
                call_user_func( array($this, $method) );
            }
        }

    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: `getHooks()` will never be fired though, since each individual method will be fired on the hook event call.

Comment: Updated the answer to initialize the methods :P

Comment: The methods don't exist, I want them to be dynamically callable. I've updated the OP to clarify.